# Soap Api request reveals secure information in faultcode as axis2ns1:server

Tags: java, soap, websphere, soapui

How do we make fault code not reveal axis2ns1:server in response when an attacker tampers the request by editing username with random characters?

There is an web.xml file which already has a error code and error page for 500 internal server error which is working fine in Jboss but not in websphere. The response should have fault code as soap:server or soap:client instead of axis2ns1:server which an attacker may use to hack. I am not sure what needs to be done to resolve this. Could someone please help

> This is how the original request looks like

```
<userName>?</userName>
```

> This is how the tampered request looks like

```
<userName>!@#$%^<>""</userName>
```

> This is how the original response looks like

```
<errorMessages><errorCode>INVALID_NUMBER</errorCode><errorMessage>INVALID_NUMBER</errorMessage><errorContext>UserProfile[0]</errorContext><highlightedField>UserProfile.userNumField1</highlightedField><errorEnvCode>DEF</errorEnvCode><errorPosition>0</errorPosition></errorMessages>
```

> This is how the response looks like for the tampered request in which I require error codes to be displayed instead of the below response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault xmlns:axis2ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <faultcode>axis2ns1:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what you mean, but according to the documentation,  [WS-Security Unifying Faults](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/troubleshoot-websphere-ws-security-general-errors), this is the fault code that's returned in the response rather than the actual exception. If you're saying that a fault that contains only: `<soapenv:Fault xmlns:axis2ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><faultcode>axis2ns1:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring><detail></detail></soapenv:Fault>`  itself is a security vulnerability,  then you should open a support case with IBM.

Comment: In burpsuite, if I tamper the request which has username from ? to ?@#&<>"" ..the response reveals 500 Internal server error along with <faultcode>axis2ns1:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring> in which I want it to be <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>some Error string</faultstring>

Comment: Which is working as designed as far as the documentation, the prefix `axis2ns1` is still set to the soap namespace, so as far as valid xml is concerned it's equivalent to to having the `soap` prefix, it's just that the WebSphere implementation is declaring the namepspace prefix of the fault as `axis2ns1`. As far as I know, there's no way of overriding that prefix name since it's being declared by the internal implementation. Why do you want to change the name of the prefix?

Comment: Since it's been considered as a security vulnerability...is there any way to override using soap Handler of something?

Comment: I guess that's my confusion, what's the vulnerability in the namespace prefix being named `axis2ns1`? I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm just curious to know how you've come to that conclusion. Is there a CVE open against it?

Comment: The thing is the client wants to have a custom error message displayed in soap response when someone tampers the name with random characters